# VBA:importing CSV file

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I created a button in ms access to import csv file into access database something like this

`DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim, TableName:="student", _
    FileName:="C:\Saurabh\test.csv", HasFieldNames:=True`

It is working fine if file name does not contains any dot. But if it contains dot for example `test1.1.csv`. It is throwing the following error

> The Microsoft access database engine could not find the object
>   test1.1.csv.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: A dot is considered to be followed by the file type extension. So Access is reading your file type as .1.csv instead of .csv

Comment: ok so how can I solve it as my file name contains dot.

Comment: Change the name of the file.

Comment: Or, if you have many files, make a temp copy of the file and call it `test.csv`. Import it and then delete it. Repeat.

Comment: I do not think chnage the name of file is a good idea. Is there any other way to do it programmatically?

Comment: Why is it not a good idea? Would 'test1 1' be acceptable to you?

Comment: my file name contains timestamp on it something like this test22.11.2014.csv which I can not change.

Comment: Use the short filename instead (8.3 characters), for instance `z.z.z.a.01.csv` becomes `ZZZA01~1.CSV`.

Comment: @Rubik files are coming from somewhere else and I can not modify or change the file name. All I can do is to make a temp file and copy data  but it's not an optimized solution I guess

Comment: I don't tell you to change anything, under windows you still can access files using their "MSDOS" name so your long filename with dots has already an equivalent in 8.3 characters. Try a "DIR /X" in command line to see that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to get short name of your file. Short name of a file is the old DOS "8.3" characters notation. You can see it with `DIR /X`:

```
                              8.3 characters file name
                                          |
                                          v
31/01/2015  23:50        29 365 798 CETOTB~1.LOG CETO.TBX-01-2015.LOG
28/02/2015  23:50        31 449 129 CETOTB~2.LOG CETO.TBX-02-2015.LOG
19/03/2015  13:12        19 190 300 CETOTB~3.LOG CETO.TBX-03-2015.LOG
31/12/2014  23:50        37 562 412 CE8EEC~1.LOG CETO.TBX-12-2014.LOG
```

As you can see above, the last column contains the long file name, and the previous one the short file name. Short file names never seem to have dot in it.

In VBA use `ShortPath` property of the `File` object to get it:

```
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder("c:\my folder")

Set objFiles = ObjFolder.Files
For Each f In objFiles
   WScript.Echo f.ShortPath
Next
```

The `TransferText` method should work fine with it.

Comment: I found this doesn't work with UNC paths. That `fso` will return the original path and not a short version of it.